# SQL Returning names with multiple spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am looking to return all names with more than one space in a single field.
For example 'John Paul Smith'. Using SQL server management studio 2005

Example I have a patients table with forename and surname

I want to return all forenames that have example 'John Paul Smith' in one field.

The query given seems to work on the surname field but not the forename. I knot for certain that the forename columns has these types of data but it is returning no results.
Con

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will probably be product specific.)

Comment: But seriously, tag your DBMS

Comment: Sorry my first time ever posting on this website. I am using SQL Server management studio 2005.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle:

```
SELECT MyField
from MyTable
where REGEXP_INSTR (MyField, ' ', 1, 2, 0, 'i') > 0
```

SQL server:

```
SELECT MyField
from MyTable
where CHARINDEX(' ', MyField, charindex(' ',MyField)+1) > 0
```

MySQL

```
select MyField
from MyTable
where length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(MyField, ' ', 2)) < length(MyField)
```

Comment: Deleting my answer and voting for yours!

Comment: Is there any reason why this would work on one column and not another? Seems to work correctly for surname column but not returning anything on forename

Comment: @Conger88 For more assistance, edit the question and provide the following: Sample data, Expected output, DBMS

Comment: @JohnHC updated with same. I noticed the Surname column doesn't allow nulls and the forename column does. Would this make a difference to the query?

Comment: Ignore my last comments! Second and third forenames are being placed into new colums. sorry.Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Conger88 please flag this as the accepted answer. It's common courtesy. Don't just walk away with the answer and not show appreciation. I know you're new here. Just reminding you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions that in my opinion are easier to read/understand than JohnHC's.

1. It can't get any simpler. Use wildcards to search for (at least) two spaces.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column LIKE '% % %';
   ```
2. Check the length after replacing the spaces

   ```
   SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE LEN(your_column) - LEN(REPLACE(your_column, ' ', '')) >= 2;
   ```